# Unable to convert pandas DataFrame to json using to_json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am aware that there are several other posts on Stack Overflow regarding this same issue, however, not a single solution found on those posts, or any other post I've found online for that matter, has worked. I have followed numerous tutorials, videos, books, and Stack Overflow posts on pandas and all mentioned solutions have failed.

The frustrating thing is that all the solutions I have found are correct, or at least they should be; I am fairly new to pandas so my only conclusion is that I am probably doing something wrong.

Here is the pandas documentation that I started with: [Pandas to_json Doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). I can't seem to get pandas to_json to convert a pandas DataFrame to a json object or json string.

Basically, I want to convert a csv string into a DataFrame, then convert that DataFrame into a json object or json string (I don't care which one). Then, once I have my json data structure, I'm going to bind it to a D3.js bar chart

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
# Declare my csv string (Works):
csvStr = '"pid","dos","facility","a1c_val"\n"123456","2013-01-01 13:37:00","UOFU",5.4\n"65432","2014-01-01 14:32:00","UOFU",5.8\n"65432","2013-01-01 13:01:00","UOFU",6.4'
print (csvStr) # Just checking the variables contents

# Read csv and convert to DataFrame (Works):
csvDf = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(csvStr))
print (csvDf) # Just checking the variables contents

# Convert DataFrame to json (Three of the ways I tried - None of them work):
myJSON = csvDf.to_json(path_or_buf = None, orient = 'record', date_format = 'epoch', double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = 'ms', default_handler = None) # Attempt 1
print (myJSON) # Just checking the variables contents

myJSON = csvDf.to_json() # Attempt 2
print (myJSON) # Just checking the variables contents

myJSON = pandas.io.json.to_json(csvDf)
print (myJSON) # Just checking the variables contents
```

The error that I am getting is:

> argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not DataFrame

Which is misleading because the documentation says "A Series or DataFrame can be converted to a valid JSON string."

Regardless, I tried giving it a string anyway, and it resulted in the exact same error.

I have tried creating a test scenario, following the exact steps from books and other tutorials and/or posts and it just results in the same error. At this point, I need a simple solution asap. I am open to suggestions, but I must emphasize that I do not have time waste on learning a completely new library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For you first attempt, the correct string is `'records'` not `'record'` This worked for me:

```
myJSON = csvDf.to_json(path_or_buf = None, orient = 'records', date_format = 'epoch', double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = 'ms', default_handler = None) # Attempt 1
```

Printing gives:

```
[{"pid":123456,"dos":"2013-01-01 13:37:00","facility":"UOFU","a1c_val":5.4},
 {"pid":65432,"dos":"2014-01-01 14:32:00","facility":"UOFU","a1c_val":5.8},
 {"pid":65432,"dos":"2013-01-01 13:01:00","facility":"UOFU","a1c_val":6.4}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! You are absolutely correct, the orient param is suppose to be 'records'! Thank you for catching that mistake. If not for another problem earlier in my code (not posted here), this solution would have fixed the problem. It turns out that the error was due my own stupid mistake resulting from a copy/paste. I'll post the details as an answer to my question. Although, I am going to mark your response as "useful" because your solution is valid for the mistake in my code. Edit: Nevermind, I can't up vote your post because I don't have enough of a reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was becuase of my own stupid mistake. While testing my use of to_json, I copy and pasted an example into my code and went from there. Thinking I had commented out that code, I proceeded to try using to_json with my test data. Turns out the error I was receiving was being thrown from the example code that I had copy and pasted. Once I deleted everything and re-wrote it using my test data it worked.

However, as user667648 (Bair) pointed out, there was another mistake in my code. The `orient` param was suppose to be `orient = 'records'` and NOT `orient = 'record'`.